# Create a JSON object using properties of a C# class

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to construct a request body for a REST api call, and I need to create a JSON object with the list of properties I want to get back.
For eg: I have this C# object that I want to get back:

```
public class SomeProperties
{
    public string TicketNumber { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To get this back, I need to put these properties in a JSON request body like this:

```
"properties": [
"ticketNumber",
"driver.name"
]
```

My attempt looks like this:

```
private string FetchProperties()
{
    var fetchProperties = new
    {
        properties = new List<string>
                        {
                            "ticketNumber",
                            "driver.name"
                        }
    };

    var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(fetchProperties, Formatting.None);
    return jsonResult;
}
```

But I don't want to hard code the properties like that.

So is there any way I can use property names from the object I want, to put in the list of strings that I made in the method above?

Thank You!

Comment: I don't exactly understand your problem.  You are trying to serialize an expected list of properties for an object graph by mapping the Type to a list of camel-cased [tag:jsonpath] property names.  But you want to deserialize *actual instance property values* on the receiving end?  How can you map type information to instance data?

Comment: Hi @dbc, I just updated the question. Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you might want to use a graph query. While possible using REST it is quite a bit of work. There are some answers here which may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40871190/advice-on-building-graphql-queries-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,you need Metadata of model.
if you use EntityFramework, you can get metadata of your model

from [this Code](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.server.net/blob/master/AspNet/Breeze.ContextProvider.EF6/EFContextProvider.cs)

and call BuildJsonMetadata() function

and if you use other mapper, I dont see any exist tool for generate metadata of model and you must generate it handly
somthing like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35222366/how-to-get-class-metadata-into-json-string)

Answer (score 0):

First of, if you serialize the class you have (`SomeProperties`), you will not get `driver.name`. Instead you will get a string like this one that shows driver as an object,

```
{
  properties : {
    "ticketNumber" : "stringvalue",
    "driver"       : {
      "name" : "stringValue"
    }
  }
}
```

That said, if you are interested in getting a json like this,

```
"properties": [
  "ticketNumber",
  "driver.name"
]
```

you will need a class (very simple one at that) that contains only a list of strings. `properties` is not an array of objects, but simply strings. From the looks of the `FetchProperties` method, you are creating an object with fetchProperties as the RootObject. Try something like this,

```
public class MyClass
{
    [JsonProperty("fetchProperties")]
    public Fetch FetchProperties { get; set; }
}
public class Fetch
{
    [JsonProperty("properties")]
    public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
}

private string FetchProperties()
{
    MyClass obj = new MyClass()
    {
        FetchProperties = new Fetch()
        {
            Properties = new List<string>() { "ticketNumber", "driver.Name" }
        }
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj); // Formatting.None is by default
}
```

Now its your choice to hard code these values or, pass them as arguments or use a local variable that contains a list of all the strings you intend to store as "properties". You cant use enums because of violation in naming convention (driver.name) so these options should suffice.